# Loop over all pages via recursion

Tags: scala, selenium, recursion

I have several pages and i want to loop over all pages via recursion:

So i have this `isNextPageExist` function to check if i have another page to visit:

```
  def isNextPageExist(): Boolean = {

  }
```

And get next page function that click on some `WebElement` and get the next page:

```
  def getNextPage(): Unit = {

  }
```

Now inside this function i want to visit first page and do my stuff and in case i have another page(s) call the function again and again, and inside each page make some calculation and return `Double`"

```
def getAllPages(value: Double):Double = {

  if(isNextPageExist)  
     // get all elements form page inside `value`
     getNextPage // get the next page
     getAllPages(value) // call the function again
}
```

Usage:

```
getAllPages(0.0)
```

This is only the `pseudo` code and i will glad for some help.

Comment: So what's the question? Do you want us to translate your pseudo code into Scala? That's not how SO works... Present a clear question and show what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David, try to avoid `Unit` return type if your function is named like getNextPage(). Better use Option[Page] and return either Some(page) or None.
But the simplest code could be better like following:

```
case class Page(url:String)

def calculateValue:Double = {here you calculate your value on the current page}

def processPage(page: Option[Page]):List[Double]{
  page match{
    case Some(p) => {
      driver.get(page.url)
      val linksToNextPage = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//your xpath goes here")
      if(linksToNextPage.size > 0){
        val nextPageLink = Page(linksToNexPage.head.getText())
        calculateValue() :: processPage(Some(Page(nextPageLink))
      } else{
        calculateValue() :: processPage(None)
      }
    }
    case None => Nil
}
```

Then you call it with the first web page as
`processPage(Some(Page("url to first page")))` and in the result you will have a list of values calculated for each page.
My code is also a pseudo-code but you should be able to make it work.

Comment: What page should return that you put it inside match ?

Comment: corrected a typo. `page` parameter of the method is actually an `Option[Page]`

Comment: But what is this Page object ?

Comment: I have several clicks before that leads me inside the first page and i want to use my 2 function: isNextPageExist and getNextPage

Comment: It is declared as case classes. If you don't know what case classes are in Scala then you need to read about them, there are a plenty of articles on this.
`Page` is declared as a case class and it encapsulates what you actually have in Selenium to access the page: its URL. You can put in this object more info if you need so.

Comment: David, I just proposed you a typical way on how to approach such task as you now have. If you think people will write for you exactly working code with exact signatures as you provided - that hardly will anyone do. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help i will try to use this approach

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not using the Java iterator interface style. It is stateless and therefore you need to keep track of the page explicitly. `case class Page` contains info about the page you are tracking.

```
case class Page()

def getNextPage(currentPage: Page): Option[Page] = { ... }

def getAllPages(currentPage: Page, value: Double, acc: List[Page]): List[Page] {
... // some calculations
  getNextPage(currentPage) match {
    case Some(p) =>  getAllPages(p, value, p :: acc)
    case None => acc
  }
}
```